# How to avoid linking zlib objs into the binary more than once in Delphi

Tags: delphi, zlib

I've been googling around for a zlib sample of how to decode gzip/deflate http encoding by only using ZLib unit (Delphi 7). I've been using Indy 10 for that but then I ran into an article saying many 3rd party components implemented their own zlib helpers eventually causing multiple zlib objects linked into the output file. I have this huge project and looking for ways to reduce the size. I did a search on the binary and turned out I had at least 4 copies of zlib linked in.

Is there a way to avoid linking zlib obj files into the binary more than once? Can I make Indy not to use/import zlib at all?

Comment: What is huge? The ZLib obj files are about 57k for each instance. So your overall gain would be about 160k most.

Comment: 200k bigger and working is better than 200k smaller and subtly broken.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you're right about the size increase. I did a quick test with a blank project and then added only ZLib unit (with a couple function calls) and it increased the binary size only by 20k. Then added IdCompressorZLib and it added another 56k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid linking zlib obj files into the binary
>   more than once?

No there is not. The linking .obj files is private to each unit. There is no way for you to detect from one unit that some other unit has linked a .obj file.

Comment: Thanks David. Looks like each zlib-dependant component I've used have their own (and usually a bit different in version) zlib objs and making them to use the very same obj set would either break them or require a lot of work, at least compared to the gain in size which is about 60k each.

Comment: Modern versions of delphi ship with a zlib unit so hopefully all sesnsible components use it.

Comment: Delphi 7 has a ZLib unit, but no one seems to like it everyone came up with their own ZLib wrappers. Which makes me wonder, is Delphi's ZLib really missing something? or they're just obsessed to do every bit of work on their own.

Comment: Is that so? I skipped D7 and went from D6 to D2010. I linked my own zlib for D6 but used the built-in for D2010. Perhaps it took a while for the 3rd party vendors to catch on to using the built in.

Comment: As you mentioned D6, I realized they try their best to make everything compatible with every Delphi version in use. That must be the reason why they all come up with their own version of everything.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's linking binary identical copies? What if the differences matter to the respective libraries linking zlib/zlibex?  If you really want to solve this problem, you should zap the INdy packages and DCU/DCP binaries that came with Delphi, and build everything from source yourself.

List for us, exactly what libraries you are using that contain ZLib.   Now obtain full source code for each, and built them all yourself.  Make them all depend (at designtime) on a common package, that contains the ZLib sources, so that the ZLib sources won't be loaded at designtime, multiple times.  Now do the same for your non-package environment; Make sure that only one copy of the ZLib source files exist, built them into obj files using a C compiler (ZLib is a C package), and then link against those, and test them to be sure they all work.  If you're not up for testing everything after changing zlib versions, abandon your attempt now.  If you can't or don't want to learn to read C code, abandon your attempt also.

In Delphi 2009 Enterprise and ARchitect, until XE, readers need to be wary that this this starts a domino effect of cascading problems which are not possible to fully recover from, if for example, you rely on DataSnap, which relies on the exact ABI of the Indy BPl that ships with Delphi.  Of course on an ancient version like Delphi 7, you can solve all these problems, and rebuild them yourself on Delphi 7.

I can't guess for you which libraries you have that might contain duplicates of Zlib, but some common places I have found it are: Any kind of zip/archive library (TurboPower Abbrevia),  network libraries (like Indy), and so on.  The JEDI JCL contains a copy of ZLib, and contains its own Zlib based compression components, which if you are using them, would get linked in.   You have to go find stuff in your own source code.  If you are that suprised to find 4 copies of Zlib (perhaps they are different versions of Zlib, even), I can guarantee you'll find even more surprises if you start exploring your code and your component source code.

Comment: +1 for the thorough comment. I was using Indy, SecureBlackbox, PNG, GIF, JPeg (which I guess only PNGObject of these 3 is using zlib) along with a bunch more. I was also using a few components that use OpenSSL (but those are not statically linked, I guess). The reason I asked this was also to avoid other linked-in objects along with zlib that share the very same libs. As for zlib, the size penalty was ignorable and a few components were using a bit different versions (even though I'm pretty sure they could all live well with the same ver).

Comment: Addon: In XE2 the included Indy claims to be using a modified ZLib "Using last zlib library (1.2.3)", while the built-in ZLib of XE2 is (1.2.5). This should definitely be solved by an appropriate IFDEF here and there.

Comment: It's worth filing that as a request on QualityCentral, Uwe. As a luminary in the community you probably get more of a vote. :-)