# How to properly upgrade Zlib in Delphi & components?

Tags: delphi, zlib

According to http://zlib.net/ news, current version is 1.2.8
downloadable as x32 and x64 objs.

Currently I have ancient version of Delphi on machine.
I'm trying to do something with it and compile my old projects.

I'm in stage of recovery /install back/ all previously used components,
recheck Demos and Samples to refresh memory or skills (few years w/o IDE).

During installation of different components I receive from IDE warnings
like this:

Cannot load package 'dcliteXX' it contains unit 'zlib,' which is also
contained in package DelphiXV0. Do you want to attempt
to load this package the next time a project is loaded?

Then I do file search across whole /AddComponents directory and find:

1. ICS suite, zlib 1.2.3 (the newest one), OBJs linked in zlib.pas /icsZlibObj

obj's: deflate, inflate, inftrees, adler32, infblock, infcodes, infutil, inffast
there also in /OBJ directory files: uncompress, compress, crc32, gzio, zutil

2. DelphiX/DirectX only zlib.dcu 1.1.3
3. hicomponents zlib.dcu 1.1.3
4. codebot, two pas files links objs:

BareZLib uses 1.0.4 from /zlib,

`{$L ZLIB\DEFLATE.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFLATE.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFTREES.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\TREES.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\ADLER32.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFBLOCK.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFCODES.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFUTIL.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFFAST.OBJ}`

and BarePNG/pngzlib uses 1.1.4 from /imgzlib

the same set of objs but different version.

5. Internet Professional Components zlib.pas for 1.1.3

the same set of objs + zlib C sources.

6. TinyDB ZlibUnit.dcu - 1.1.3, + pascal version of Zlib sources
7. JEDI ver 1.104 JCL zlibh.dcu 1.2.3
8. VGVCL unit vgZLib uses zlib, currently it is 1.1.3
9. IDE /lib/zlib.dcu is 1.0.4 :D

quite mess

---

zlib package from zlib.net has win32 objs:

deflate, inflate, inftrees, trees, adler32,

infback, infast and... compress, crc32.

and ZlibEx.pas, ZlibExAPI.pas, ZlibExGZ.pas

---

I thought at 1st: I can copy new *.obj's to /implobj directories of components
and rebuild packages to refresh its *.bpl, *.dcp packages

but - I'm confused with missing

`{$L ZLIB\INFBLOCK.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFCODES.OBJ}`
`{$L ZLIB\INFUTIL.OBJ}`

in current zlib_archive.

2nd thought if I manipulate mine {Delphi}/lib path and put the newest zlib using
component path at high place all compiled projects and rebuild packages get new zlib.dcu.
/testing needed they will works/

3rd thought - maybe I change all components unit declarations from Zlib to ZlibEx and that
way all freshly compiled binaries get current zlib implementation/binaries.

and one doubt for end - why it is not possible to unify linked obj's to zlib/pngzlib units?
If yes, how to assure png components will works with new Zlib release?

[base of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866413/how-to-avoid-linking-zlib-objs-into-the-binary-more-than-once-in-delphi)

Comment: Quite **OBJ hell**, indeed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "ancient version of Delphi". Does it by any chance have a more commonly used name?

Comment: I know it is far below of your requirements, but I would go the following way: 1) upgrade library's `zlib` (see http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_faq.html#faq10 and corresponding README) 2) eliminate "proprietary" dependencies and link baseline zlib for all 3rd party libraries with source 3) push that update into 3rd party repositories/issue trackers. W/o source you are out of luck, unfortunately

Comment: 1). update (Delphi interface) done. 2b). possible (sources from components onboard), C zlib sources onboard, Pas translations from previous version ~1.1.3 onboard - for comparision with C source). 3). partially impossible due "end of support". QUESTION: How to remove dependency from Inprise compiled dcliteX0.bpl? - Simply use new ZlibEX interface everywhere (for new projects) and accept internal IDE old dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for any new zlib .obj files. If I were you I would stick with the .obj files that shipped with the components. Trying to put new .obj files in is just asking for trouble. You'll likely have to modify many of the components to make them work. And for what gain?

If you were using modern Delphi, and up-to-date components, then, if the components were well implemented, the components would use the zlib unit that ships in the Delphi RTL. You could modify the components to use a single shared zlib unit. But again, at what gain? And now you'd be using modified versions of the components which could make a future Delphi upgrade more complex.

It seems to me that your main problem is that you have multiple design time packages with a unit named zlib. Here's what I would do:

1. Find out which packages have clashing units.
2. Do you really need all of the clashing packages? Are you using all of the components? If not, then drop the unused ones.
3. Perhaps you need one component in one project, and a different one in a different project? If so, load packages selectively only for projects that use them.
4. Do you need design time packages for the clashing components? If not, and if you are not using run time packages, then don't load the design time packages.
5. As a last resort, rename one of the zlib units to, say, ComponentNameZlib. This will side step the clash.

Comment: many thanks for clash resolving and suggestion to keep the older one. Anyway I don't understand why I'm pushed to have 'version hell'.

Comment: It all stems from older Delphi versions shipping without zlib and so third party components being compelled to include it. Sadly the Delphi component world isn't very good at sharing. If this was Linux you'd just take a dependency on a different package. But there was never a standard package that contained zlib that other components could rely on.

Comment: I have sources of packages and would like to follow @Warren P idea. I have time and will (to try and to check), I need methodology and cold answer - it is possible to have one or 2 /pngzlib/ versions of /in this example/ zlib library. I want to gain experience in upgrading packages (clash resolving will be valuable too).

Comment: I've no idea what you are asking me now. Sorry.